# Sklearn text classification model returns single class regardless of actual content

Tags: python, predict, sklearn-pandas

I am building text classification model. And for some reason it returns me single class regardless of actual text or number of rows. Here's what I am doing:

```
X = df['text']
y = df['type']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 13)

pipe_mnnb = Pipeline(steps = [('tf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('mnnb', MultinomialNB())])

pgrid_mnnb = {
 'tf__max_features' : [100, 250, 500],
 'tf__stop_words' : ['english', None],
 'tf__ngram_range' : [(1,1),(1,2)],
 'tf__use_idf' : [True, False],
 'mnnb__alpha' : [0.1, 0.5, 1]
}
gs_mnnb = GridSearchCV(pipe_mnnb,pgrid_mnnb,cv=5,n_jobs=-1)
gs_mnnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then I use following lines of code to double check results:

```
preds_mnnb = gs_mnnb.predict(X)
df['preds'] = preds_mnnb
```

Everything looks ok. Now, I create a new dataframe I want to apply classification model to(I am using dummy data here):

```
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'text':['abc text',
                           'xyz text',
                           'mnopr text',
                           'ijk text',
                           'rrr text',
                           'xxx text']}
                        )
```

| text |
| --- |
| abc text |
| xyz text |
| mnopr text |
| ijk text |
| rrr text |
| xxx text |

If I use this approach then I get correctly classified results with different classes:

```
test_data2 = test_data.iloc[:,0]
gs_mnnb.predict(test_data2)
```

> array(['class A', 'class B', 'class C',
> 'class C', 'class D', 'class B'],
> dtype='<U30')

But when I dont apply iloc data selection:

```
gs_mnnb.predict(test_data)
```

Then I will get only this kind of response, regardless how many rows or what they contain:

> array(['class A'], dtype='<U30')

Answer (score 0):

If the model needs to work with `DataFrames`, one thing I would try is making sure that `X` and `y` are `DataFrames` - currently, they are `Series`. Change the first two lines of code like this (note the extra square brackets):

```
X = df[['text']]
y = df[['type']]
```

Comment: Thanks.
After following your suggestions I get following error when fitting the model:

**ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 149]**

Although shapes for data are same:
`X_train.shape
y_train.shape`
(149, 1)

(149, 1)